# ListView with checkbox

Tags: android, database, listview, checkbox

How do i on checkboxselected , show a toast that has data from database?

Thank you.

Comment: You take a ListView which contains a checkbox, register a listener and display the toast with the given data... could you at least show how far you got? Ask a specific question please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is not quite specific this could help (assuming that your checkbox is called `CheckBox01` and the statement `Checkbox myCheckBox;` is somewhere above)

```
myCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
myCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (myCheckBox.isChecked()) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Replace this with data from database string", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```